# how to query a derived entity set with the OData .net client c#

Tags: c#, .net, odata

Used:
Microsoft.OData.Client: 6.17.0
OData v4 Client Code Generator: 2.4.0

I generated with the OData v4 Client Code Generator for a c# project to access and work with the OData service.

I am struggling to get a derived entity set. Based on the v4 service [TripPin](http://www.odata.org/blog/trippin-new-odata-v4-sample-service/)
I Would like to access Flights which are of base type PlanItem. The HTTP query is: http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW/People('russellwhyte')/Trips(1003)/PlanItems/Microsoft.OData.SampleService.Models.TripPin.Flight

in C# I only have:

```
... .PlanItems.ExecuteAsync() -> gets only the base type
```

or

```
... .PlanItmes.ByKey(xyz).CastToFlight().ExecuteAsync() ->only gets one derived item
```

the expected solution below is not available:

```
... .PlanItems.OfType<Flight>()
```

Is there a way to get the derived entity set of flights in c# just like I can with the HTTP query above? What do I have to check in the metadata document to get the API OfType?

Thanks

Comment: I don't have any idea on this. If you can do something like PlanItems.Include("Flight").ExecuteAsync().. have you tried it ??

Comment: Include() is not a option in the generated model